# xml node deletion not working properly in java using dom parser?

Tags: java, xml, dom, nodes, xmlnode

Here i have xml node where i'm displaying and selecting particular node to delete.For my below xml file and code ,only first node is deleting though i select second node.

```
<root>
 <book>  <!--node 1 -->
 <id>1111</id>
 <name>abacd</name>
 <author>abcd</author>
 <price>700</price>
 <category>abcd</category>
</book>
<book>  <!--node 2 -->
 <id>2222</id>
 <name>abacd</name>
 <author>abcd</author>
 <price>700</price>
 <category>abcd</category>
</book>
 <book>  <!--node 3 -->
  <id>3333</id>
  <name>abacd</name>
  <author>abcd</author>
  <price>700</price>
 <category>abcd</category>
</book>
</root>
```

and my java code to delete node as

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
    int nodeValue = Integer.parseInt(nodeNumber);
    //nodeValue is node number eg: 2;
    NodeList bookList = doc.getElementsByTagName("book");
    for (int i = 1; i <= bookList.getLength(); i++) {
        if (i == nodeValue) {
            Element rootElement = (Element) doc.getElementsByTagName("book").item(0);
            Element idElement = (Element) doc.getElementsByTagName("id").item(0);
            idElement.getParentNode().removeChild(idElement);
            Element nameElement = (Element) doc.getElementsByTagName("name").item(0);
            nameElement.getParentNode().removeChild(nameElement);
            Element authorElement = (Element) doc.getElementsByTagName("author").item(0);
            authorElement.getParentNode().removeChild(authorElement);
            Element priceElement = (Element) doc.getElementsByTagName("price").item(0);
            priceElement.getParentNode().removeChild(priceElement);
            Element categoryElement = (Element) doc.getElementsByTagName("category").item(0);
            categoryElement.getParentNode().removeChild(categoryElement);
            rootElement.getParentNode().removeChild(rootElement);
            doc.normalize();
        }
    }
```

could anybody guide me where to change my code.

Answer (score 0):

You always call the first node by this

```
doc.getElementsByTagName("book").item(0);
```

Instead try to use

```
doc.getElementsByTagName("book").item(nodeValue);
```

Or use `bookList.item(nodeValue)` to access the node directly

Comment: StanislavL,Thanks for ur reply.I found my answer please check below.

Answer (score 0):

if we want to delete node according to node number then below code helps.I got my answer by this

```
int nodeValue = Integer.parseInt(nodeNumber);
    NodeList bookList = doc.getElementsByTagName("book");
    Node nNode = bookList.item(nodeValue);
    if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
        eElement.getParentNode().removeChild(nNode);
    }
```

It will delete selected node (eg:2).